# Changing the order of an integral

Tags: integration

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{1}  \int_{0}^{1-y} f(x,y,z) \ dz \ dy \ dx $

To change the order of the integral in the form

$\int \int  \int f(x,y,z) \ dy \ dz \ dx $

My work:

$z = 1-y$

$y = 1-z$

$0< y < 1-z$

$\sqrt{x} < z< 1$

$0<x<1$

That is

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{ \sqrt{x}}^{1}  \int_{0}^{1-z} f(x,y,z) \ dy \ dz \ dx $

Is this correct. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not correct. You have changed the region itself. You only need to change the order of integration and hence the bounds of variables.

For example, you changed the parabolic cylinder from $y = \sqrt x \,$ to $ \,z = \sqrt x \,$.

Please note this is the region is in the first octant bound below by the parabolic cylinder $y = \sqrt x$ and above by the plane $y + z = 1 \,$.

So for order of integration $dy \, dz \, dx$,

$\sqrt x \leq y \leq 1 - z, 0 \leq z \leq 1 - \sqrt x, \,0 \leq x \leq 1 $

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome!